Auto-Rig Pro no inverse kinematics on the 2nd hand
I have a question about the "Auto-Rig Pro" add-on. I've been searching for a long time for how to enable reverse kinematics for fingers, but I couldn't. When I finally found it, I saw that it wasn't on my right arm.


What am I doing wrong?
The add-on version is 3.72.27.
Who is looking for how to enable IK:

